# Gateway is down because of PHP code in one situation

Tags: php, html

Here is the code (HTML / PHP) :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <select id="horseSize" name="horseSize" class="form-control" >
         <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($horseSize); ?>" selected><?php echo htmlspecialchars($horseSize); ?> m</option>
            <?php
               $i = 0.50;
               while($i <= 2.00){
                  if ($i != $horseSize){
            ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(number_format($i, 2)) ; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(number_format($i, 2)) ; ?> m</option>
            <?php
                     $i = $i + 0.01;
                  }
               }
            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

$horseSize comes from a SQL query and is working fine. Th problem is in displaying webpage.

When i am trying to display this webpage, my website goes down because of gateway giving no answer. This triggers only in one situation : if the variable value of $horseSize is inferior to 1. As if it was not possible to display something like 0,....

Maybe I did something wrong in this code, but I tried many times to fix, I couldn't reach it.

Comment: Your loop obviously runs infinitely.

Comment: Indeed, $i was incremented into the if condition. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are incrementing $i only under if condition, so value like 0.50 it will always never increase. Also floating point comparison will not work. please read: [Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <select id="horseSize" name="horseSize" class="form-control" >
         <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($horseSize); ?>" selected><?php echo htmlspecialchars($horseSize); ?> m</option>
            <?php
               $i = 0.50;
               $precision = 0.00001;
               while($i <= 2.00){
                if(abs($i-$horseSize) > $precision) {
            ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(number_format($i, 2)) ; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(number_format($i, 2)) ; ?> m</option>
            <?php
                     $i = $i + 0.01;
                  } else {
                    $i = $i + 0.01;
                  }
               }
            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```